# How to sum related values that comes each time Runnable task is executed?

Tags: java, runnable

I have the following code from of a Runnable task from [here](https://www.mkyong.com/java/java-scheduledexecutorservice-examples/) that I customize for my purporse and that runs every second ten times. There are 3 arrays with 10 elements each of them. **The arrays are only an artificial way to reproduce the values of real code, so the solution doesn't need to do any array operation, because is supposed that we don't know what is the next value for each array each time the `task1` is called**

The current code shows the Nth value of each array each time the task1 is called.

As you can see, the array `arr_fruits` contains repeated fruits, so I'd like to print the sum of elements of each array for repeated fruits in a single line.

The current output is this (it contains 10 lines):

```
# : arr_x : arr_y  : fruit
0 : 7     : 2      : Apple
1 : 14    : 4      : Apple
2 : 24    : 9      : Apple
3 : 50    : 22     : Orange
4 : 97    : 45     : Banana
5 : 199   : 91     : Banana
6 : 400   : 179    : Grapes
7 : 792   : 353    : Grapes
8 : 1590  : 713    : Apple
9 : 3176  : 1421   : Orange

Count is 10, cancel the scheduledFuture!
```

And I would like the output to be like this:

```
# : arr_x : arr_y  : fruit
1 : 45    : 15     : Apple
2 : 50    : 22     : Orange
3 : 296   : 136    : Banana
4 : 1192  : 532    : Grapes
5 : 1590  : 713    : Apple
6 : 3176  : 1421   : Orange
```

This is the sum of values for each fruit shown in a single line. 
For example:

For `Apple and arr_x`:  7 + 14 + 24 = 45

For `Grapes and arr_y`: 179 + 353 = 532

In the code below I put an `if-else` commented code that is the part for which I need help. I don't know how to sum/accumulate the values for the same fruit and print
and a single line and then print the next values when the fruit changes.

I hope make sense.

```
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.concurrent.ScheduledExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.ScheduledFuture;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

public class ScheduledExecutorRepeat {
    private static int count = 0;
    private static String fruit = "";
    private static String line = "";
    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {

       ScheduledExecutorService ses = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1);

        Runnable task1 = () -> {
            int[] arr_x = new int[] {7,14,24,50,97,199,400,792,1590,3176};
            int[] arr_y = new int[] {2,4,9,22,45,91,179,353,713,1421};
            String[] arr_fruits = {"Apple","Apple","Apple","Orange","Banana","Banana","Grapes","Grapes","Apple","Orange"};             

            //if ( fruit == arr_fruits[count] ) {
            //    ///Some code
            //} else {
            //  ///Some other code
            //}

            line = count +  " : " + arr_x[count] + " : " + arr_y[count] + " : " + arr_fruits[count];
            System.out.println( line );
            count++;
        };

        // init Delay = 2, repeat the task every 1 second
        ScheduledFuture<?> scheduledFuture = ses.scheduleAtFixedRate(task1, 2, 1, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

        while (true) {
            Thread.sleep(1000);
            if (count == 10) {
                System.out.println("Count is 10, cancel the scheduledFuture!");
                scheduledFuture.cancel(true);
                ses.shutdown();
                break;
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Is _the same_ Runnable being executed? (It looks like it is here.) If so, you can make a regular ordinary stateful class that `implements Runnable` and keeps a counter. Keep in mind that your counter needs to be thread-safe (atomic or volatile).

Comment: Hi. Yes, there is only one Runnable. I'm very new to Java. May you show me some example about what you suggest please.

Comment: *is supposed that we don't know what is the next value for each array each time the task1 is called* How is the task "called" to provide the value? This makes a difference here.

Comment: @chrylis Lets say the application is receiving continuously entries of number of sold fruits from store x and store y.  Suppose the fruits sold change each second, so the data is changing each second but sometimes data transmitted  comes apples more than once, grapes once and so on. Then, the next values are unknown but the computation/sum should be done almost in the moment that happens. The `ScheduledFuture` calls the `task1` every second, in that way is called and stops in a predefined number of calls(10 in this case) . I hope make sense.

Comment: The scheduler can't provide any input when it calls the task. If you're wanting to "push" data from a supplier of some kind into multiple calls, then a scheduler (and a `Runnable`) is the wrong design.

Comment: @chrylis the use of arrays, runnable are only to generate the data for example purposes that represents very similar the real code. The logic to accomplish my goal I think should go within the task1 {} and is where Iḿ stuck in how to identify group of fruits of the same type and print the sum and if it comes a single fruit only print without sum.

Comment: It's hard to understand from a fake example what you really need, but perhaps you're looking for a `Map<String, int[]>` or similar?

Comment: @chrylis Thanks for suggestion. I was seeing what you suggest, maybe could be a way to do it. I´ll continue  looking for a way in how to make the sum of values of the previous fruit in the moment it changes to another type of fruit that is where I'm stuck.